# Google Glass application change timeline name

Tags: android, google-glass, timeline

Im developing a live card application for a Google Glass. When I look at the timeline of the Google Glass my app is called "show demo". I want to change this, but i cant find out where to do this. The only thing i can find is the voice_trigger.xml file where you can set a voice command for starting the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open res/values/strings.xml, your app_name should be listed as:

```
<string name="app_name">[APP NAME HERE]</string>
```

Change [APP NAME HERE] for the wanted name for your app.

For a better explenation look at the following link under "Defining Menu Appearance":

[A Tutorial for Aspiring Google Glass Developers: Building Your First Glass App](http://www.toptal.com/google-glass/building-your-first-glass-app-a-tutorial-for-aspiring-google-glass-developers)